# Adding an "AddStream" method to TMultipartFormData for use with TNetHTTPClient.Post

Tags: delphi, http-post

Using Delphi 10.2.3,

I want to upload an image from a TStream to a web server using TNetHTTPClient.Post and TMultipartFormData.

My problem is that the TMultipartFormData class does not have an 'AddStream' function (I'm assuming it needs a file name to generate the mime type), so I decided to add my own since I know the mime types (and a valid file name) in advance.

I never used class inheritance or class helpers in Delphi 10.2.3 and after reading and trying it out I've reached a point where I'm obviously missing something but can't figure out what.

I tried:

```
Type
  TMultipartFormDataStream = class (TMultipartFormData)
    procedure AddStream(AStream : TStream; const AFieldName, AFilePath: string);
  end;

procedure TMultipartFormDataStream.AddStream(AStream : TStream; const AFieldName, AFilePath: string);
var
  LType: string;
begin
  AdjustLastBoundary;
  WriteStringLn('--' + FBoundary);
  WriteStringLn(sContentDisposition + ': form-data; name="' + AFieldName + '"; filename="' + ExtractFileName(AFilePath) + '"'); // do not localize
  LType := GetFileMIMEType(AFilePath);
  WriteStringLn(sContentType + ': ' + LType + #13#10); // We need 2 line break here   // do not localize
  try
    FStream.CopyFrom(AStream, 0);
  finally
  end;
  WriteStringLn('');
end;
```

However, none of the inherited's class private functions are accessible.

I also tried using a class helper instead of directly inheriting, but again the private functions are not accessible and I would rather not use an RTTI hack.

What is the best solution/work-around to upload the image from a stream using TNetHTTPClient? Do I really have to save the stream to a file just to add it to the multipart form data?

Comment: What you are asking for is not doable. You can't access `TMultipartFormData`'s private internals. File a feature request with Embarcadero to add `TStream` support, and then find another solution in the meantime. For instance, Indy's `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` has an overloaded `AddFormField()` method that accepts `TStream` input.

Comment: Submitted at https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21253 - Since I'm developing cross-platform, I can't use Indy, so for now the work-around is to save to file and then using the AddFile function.

Comment: "*Since I'm developing cross-platform, I can't use Indy*" - why? Indy is cross platform. It supports all of the same platforms that Delphi does (and more, via FreePascal)

Comment: I wasn't aware that Indy was cross platform using Delphi, especially with regards to https, all the comments I read seemed to imply that https with Indy is not cross platform.

Comment: Indy's HTTPS support is cross-platform, for the most part. The  caveat is Indy's *default* TLS library is OpenSSL on all platforms, but Google dropped OS support for OpenSSL in Android 6. Some people have had success manually including OpenSSL libs in their Android 6+ deployments on some devices, but other people have not. So Indy's TLS support is spotty on Android 6+, unless you are lucky to make OpenSSL work, or use another TLS library that you manage to hook into Indy with a custom IOHandler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved in Delphi 10.3 where the extended the interface with the ability to use streams directly.